# Why is it showing module not defined even though it is defined?

Tags: python, speech-recognition

This is what it shows:

> No module named process_text

This is the program:

```py
while(1):  
        assistant_speaks("What can i do for you?") 
        text = get_audio().lower() 

        if text == 0: 
            continue

        if "exit" in str(text) or "bye" in str(text) or "sleep" in str(text): 
            assistant_speaks("Ok bye, "+ name+'.') 
            break
        # calling process text to process the query 
        process_text( text )

def process_text( text ): 

 try:

    if 'search' in text or 'play' in text: 
        search_web(text) 
        return

    elif "who are you" in text or "define yourself" in text: 
        speak = '''Hello, I am Person. Your Assistant. 
        I am here to make your life easier. You can command me to perform various tasks such as calculating sums or opening applications etcetera'''
        assistant_speaks(speak) 
        return
except : 

    assistant_speaks("I don't understand, I can search the web for you, Do you want to continue?") 
    ans = get_audio() 
    if 'yes' in str(ans) or 'yeah' in str(ans): 
        search_web(text)
```

Comment: Fix your formatting

Comment: If you edit your post, select your code sample, and use the Code Sample button (`{}`), it will format your code properly for display. Also, there are many extraneous blank lines that should be removed.